# Gc overhead limit exceeded is showing after adding google play services library

Tags: google-play-services, eclipse-luna

If I add google play services library to my project, then gc overhead limit exceeded is showing!

This is eclipse.ini content:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.200.v20140603-1326
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
1024M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
1024m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-Xms512m
-Xmx1024m
```

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing the same problem. Then I set the values to 2048 for xms and xmx. However high CPU uses was observed for intial few seconds, but it worked.

```
-Xms2048m
-Xmx2048m
```

Comment: Where exactly did you set this?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky in eclipse.ini file available in root folder of Eclipse installation.